# I cannot run azure functions core tools locally

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, npm-install, azure-functions-runtime

I have installed azure functions core tools on Ubuntu. But It does not run and when I tried to run this command it return this error:

```html
internal/child_process.js:323
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn EACCES
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
    at main (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/lib/main.js:12:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/lib/main.js:21:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

And Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems beta-23 is broken. Revert to -22, `sudo npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@2.0.1-beta.22`

Comment: Hi evilSnobu, Ihave tried to run yuor commande but i got this error
`
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! azure-functions-core-tools@2.0.1-beta.22 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ib92/.npm/_logs/2018-03-10T21_19_03_039Z-debug.log
`

Answer (score 2):

`beta.23` does have an issue on mac and linux but `@core` tag should be on `beta.23-1` which should have that issue fixed.

Try running `npm -g list azure-functions-core-tools` to verify the version you have it should be

```
/usr/lib
└── azure-functions-core-tools@2.0.1-beta.23-1
```

and **not**

```
/usr/lib
└── azure-functions-core-tools@2.0.1-beta.23
```

Alternatively you can fix `beta.23` by running <s>`sudo chmod 755 $(which func)`</s> Edit: it's actually `sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/func`

I'm also preparing a new release due to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/397) and will be released shortly

**Edit:**

And btw, if you're running on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint, we now have a deb package in the microsoft sources. 
so you can add that and run `apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools` instead of npm. [The instructions are in the README](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#linux)

**Edit 2:**

and for Mac OS you can now do

```
brew tap azure/functions
brew install azure-functions-core-tools
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad 
npm -g list azure-functions-core-tools
show  this :
/usr/lib
└── (empty)

Comment: how did you install the cli? Can you try running `npm i -g azure-fucntions-core-tools@core --unsafe-perm true`?

Comment: And btw, if you're running on Debian/Ubuntu/Mint, we now have a deb package in the microsoft sources. 
so you can add that and run `apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools` instead of npm. [The instructions are in the README](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#linux)

Comment: @Hizeoui, this is fixed in `beta.24` so just npm install and you should be good to go.